# driver get don't show next button

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I wrote this code for scrap all of the venue titles from website:

```
url="https://thevendry.com/venues/search/are/dubai/dubai"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
Titles = []
while True:
    Title_elements = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'.before\:tw-h-full')
    for item in Title_elements:
        print(item.text)
        Titles.append(item.text)
    next_button = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,
                                       '//*[@id="__next"]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/a[2]/div[1]/span')
    if next_button:
        ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(next_button[0]).click().perform()
        time.sleep(10)
    else:
        break
```

But I get titles from first page and next button don't work!

Then I check code step by step and I realize that next button don't show on driver get selenium!
How can I fix it?

image of website:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LxBG7.jpg)

image of website under test:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjrAz.jpg)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Issue you have there that your site doesn't show next pages for not authorised users.

That explains, why you see it in your browser and don't see in automation.

So, to display next button you need to log in:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
import time

url = 'https://thevendry.com/sign-in'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
def login(email, password):
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[type=email]'))).send_keys(email)
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[type=password]'))).send_keys(password)
    submit = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[type=submit]')))
    submit.click()
    wait.until(EC.staleness_of(submit))
login('tebage3567@ibtrades.com', 'temporary111')

url="https://thevendry.com/venues/search/are/dubai/dubai"
driver.get(url)
Titles = []
while True:
    Title_elements = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'.before\:tw-h-full')
    for item in Title_elements:
        print(item.text)
        Titles.append(item.text)
    next_button = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,
                                       "//a[.//*[text()='Next']]")
    # your further code
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Fluent wait mechanism, and add the logic to poll for every 10s to check the availability of the button. Or, if the button is in a disabled state, to check use below lines of code.

```
boolean enaORDis=driver.find element(By.xpath("    ")).isEnabled();
                                 if(enaORDis==true){                                                                                                                
                        print("Button is enabled or present");                                                                                  }
else
{                                                                                                                                                             print(button is not present or enabled);                                                                                 write the wait mechanism to pool the page every 10s to check button availability.
}
```